# Import jquery-ui to angular project with ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, ecmascript-6

I wanted to use angular-ui-sortable in my project and so I tried to import jquery-ui for that matter but with no luck so far. Of course before all that I add the package by

```
meteor npm install --save jquery-ui
```

I have tried importing the library using the following:

```
import 'jquery-ui';
```

and then adding it as a dependency in my module

```
angular.module('myModule', ['jquery-ui']);
```

but that gives the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module jquery-ui due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'jquery-ui' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I have also tried importing it this way

```
import jqueryui from 'jquery-ui';
```

but this did not work too. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: which angular version are you using

Comment: I am using Angular 1